# Sorting Objects with Unknown Index Types

Tags: typescript

I have a sort function that I am trying to add TypeScript to. I have run into one issue. The function is supposed to be reusable so it wont know anything about the objects its supposed to sort. More specifically, it wont know the type of each individual key/index. I have seen `keyof` can be used for problems similar to this but I dont know of a way I could pass a type/interface to the sort function.

Here is the full error given by my IDE:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'Object'.   No index signature
> with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Object'.ts(7053)

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gJ2AeQEYCsIGNhQLxQDeAUFGVANYQgBcUAzsAgJYB2A5gDSnkAmzCbMGZxWdRiw7EAvsWIAzAK6scI1lACyIeEgBiy1aIAUvAIbBTdNJhwBtALqcoWRQkGtgO4HS-WhASmIScigAGwhcekQLVHD8KFsAOmSzC3sAbjkQqKRTWIhEnOAjI0soPxwnVCsMAPwAPiIeELJmeSgjAEJTWxc3CA8vRKoQeygAH3GoHr73T2jh6jGAHihUXtc5oZH7fyaWg6hBYFd1WYH5pET+QUN1PAeoAHJTeiwB-g4nqAB+KABaACMUDogMyhygsghbQ6nXW50GCx2EymM02F22SygjTWG36iKuOz2wQh5GOp2c6IJwGuAiEanwjxebw+bHY3z+wLoQPBhyhh3JCHUAAZeWRpP5MrJiKBIFAAEJwOAUeIk1q8OisRQAW1QEAQ3BCwmA4XETDZhvIYEUsWY9AAFhANQxzRwJlAtaFQpayFh7aYwMB9fRNTq9QgZHIsKJGGslRR6PFbM0iFBmM7AU5jabnjALMIsFAACrgNlQeSIKAAER12uYEHoTyc1ttDqddCeACZhd3-sKAMxAztFwEADhoABZATRhaPEv2AJydgBaTec-sDwdBAFZIT7U+m6J2s8wTRAO0X7WzEwBJSisOAAd2mqDgilwJcgMCwLEDa5boR2o6zpdj2wp9gAbH2ADsI7jhO47dokE7bqOq5OH6AZBggIZQMC0j7oQabOv2J5nh2AAKCBwMANHgA2UAAG6JgAwqErz0A2-42oBbYgd2vbCtuQLCkWA6TohwrIah6HrlhW5QBBkLEBkchaF4+gqMIxivsq9BOIQIwdtmEBrjc9KiB2rzvKwnzshKmTqdEml3EYukJgZRnPABQFOmZdJ3B2vANjZdlPA5xBOXoBjaawbnxvpRBeU8mGbjh-m3LFQUhayXwOUAA)

```
type SortObject = {
    key: string,
    direction: string
}

function MySortFunction(data: Object[], currentSort: SortObject)
{
    let sortable = [...data];

    sortable.sort((a: Object, b: Object) => {
        if (!a[currentSort.key] || a[currentSort.key] < b[currentSort.key]) {
            return currentSort.direction === 'ascending' ? -1 : 1;
        }
        if (!b[currentSort.key] || a[currentSort.key] >  b[currentSort.key]) {
            return currentSort.direction === 'ascending' ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
}

type Book = {
    id: number,
    title: string,
    published: string | null,
    chapters: number
}

const books = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Static Typing for Dummies', published: '2020-03-12T18:41:08.392Z', chapters: 15 },
    { id: 2, title: 'Things I know about TypeScript', published: '2020-06-07T18:48:20.458Z', chapters: 1 },
    { id: 3, title: 'Prototypes vs Classes', published: '2020-05-10T03:48:20.458Z', chapters: 6 }
];

MySortFunction(books, {key: 'title', direction: 'ascending'});
MySortFunction(books, {key: 'published', direction: 'descending'});
MySortFunction(books, {key: 'chapters', direction: 'descending'});
```

**Edit: 2021-04-15**

Looks like this could very well be handled with generics.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#generic-functions

**Edit: 2021-04-17**

It was suggested that I change my `SortObject` to:

```
type SortObject = {
    key: keyof Object,
    direction: string
}
```

however that introduces other errors:

```
Type '"title"' is not assignable to type 'keyof Object'.
Type '"published"' is not assignable to type 'keyof Object'.
Type '"chapters"' is not assignable to type 'keyof Object'.
```

Comment: Note that `<` and `>` are really only appropriate if the type of the operands is `number`, in which case using `-` would be more straightforward. For strings, `localeCompare` makes more sense. So I would lean toward separate implementations...

Comment: Did you tried something like `data.sort((a: Record<string, any>, b: Record<string, any>))`?

Comment: please share reproducable example

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for the tip I will look into using `localeCompare`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I hope my current example is more ideal. Additionally, if you have any resources you're willing to share on sorting mixed types I would appreciate them. Thank you

Comment: @FamousAv8er - **Great edit!!** I'm literally finishing up for the night but hopefully a TS person takes a look. If not, I'll look tomorrow, but my TS is about 70%. :-) I know this can be done...